# Forcing Ajax to get cached version

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, browser-cache

I am creating a Google-Chrome extension and I want to be able to pull some images that a website is loading and put them in the extension. In some cases, this can result in a lot of requests to the server, effectively slowing it down. These images are loaded when the user visits the page, so there is no need for the extension to request the images again. Is there any way to get the data without pulling the data from the server again?

Comment: Doesn't the server send appropriate cache headers or what is your problem?

Comment: It is not my server. I cannot change the cache headers. It doesn't look like they are using any.

Comment: Then I guess you should try to overwrite/set them from your extension

Comment: That would be what I'm trying to do...

Comment: @Bergi Setting Cache control headers from the extension has no influence on caching.

Comment: @RobW: Thanks, didn't know that. Is there anything that lets you manipulate the cache from an extension then?

Comment: There's no generic method, unfortunately. @FranzPayer Can you share more information on how the images are loaded/used?

Comment: They are loaded via ajax requests. I am able to log the requests as they pass by and then make my own requests via ajax as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using [binary Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data), you can pull the images as `Blob` objects, which [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FFileReader) can convert to a base64 URL string.

1. Fetch the binary data of the image as an `ArrayBuffer` and store it in a `Blob`:

   ```
   var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
   oReq.open("GET", "/myfile.png", true);
   oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

   oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
     var blob = new Blob([oReq.response], {type: "image/png"});
     // step 2 goes here...
   };

   oReq.send();
   ```

   (According to the spec, you can also do `oReq.responseType = "blob"` to make `oReq.response` a `Blob` immediately, instead of an `ArrayBuffer`. I'm not 100% sure if this is actually supported yet.)
2. Read the `Blob` with `FileReader`:

   ```
   var fr = new FileReader();
   fr.onload = function(e) {
       var dataUrl = e.target.result;
       // step 3 goes here...
   }
   fr.readAsDataURL(blob);
   ```
3. Finally, you have the URL stored in `dataUrl`. Assign it directly to the `src` attribute of an image element:

   ```
   document.getElementById("myimg").src = dataUrl;
   ```

   To avoid performing the fetch in the future, store the data URL in `localStorage` or an IndexedDB store.

Comment: Doesn't quite solve the problem, my extension still has to load the images. The problem was that the original webpage (not my code) loads the page. Then, after the page is loaded, my extension wants to get the cached version of the resources. Your code would only be helpful if my extension had to load the resources multiple times from the extension.